# How to access data from a nested object then pass into href attribute after user selects an option from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-objects

I am trying to get the link associated with whatever option the user selects from a dropdown list into my href attribute for every div in my html by using eventListener.

Already i have created all this links and stored them as objects. I am only able to access them when i call specific keys. Each object nested within the main parent object has three keys and values {keys:values}.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .form {
      width: 25%;
      height: inherit;
      overflow: auto;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="form" action="result.html" method="POST">
    <h1 class="productName">Div 1</h1>
    <img src="img\red.jpg" alt="Trial Image" width="10%" height="100%" class="images productImg"><br>
    <select name="category" class="package">
      <option value="Selected an option" default>Select an option</option>
      <option value="Business Plan">Business Plan</option>
      <option value="Feasibility Report">Feasibility Report</option>
    </select>

    <a href="" class="submit"><button type="submit" >Try it</button></a>
  </form>

  <form class="form" action="result.html" method="POST">
    <h1 class="productName">Div 2</h1>
    <img src="img\yellow.jpg" alt="Trial Image" width="10%" height="100%" class="images productImg"><br>
    <select name="category" class="package">
      <option value="Selected an option" default>Select an option</option>
      <option value="Business Plan">Business Plan</option>
      <option value="Feasibility Report">Feasibility Report</option>
    </select>

    <a href="" class="submit"><button type="submit" >Try it</button></a>
  </form>

  <form class="form" action="result.html" method="POST">
    <h1 class="productName">Div 3</h1>
    <img src="img\blue.jpg" alt="Trial Image" width="10%" height="100%" class="images productImg"><br>
    <select name="category" class="package">
      <option value="Selected an option" default>Select an option</option>
      <option value="Business Plan">Business Plan</option>
      <option value="Feasibility Report">Feasibility Report</option>
    </select>

    <a href="" class="submit"><button type="submit" >Try it</button></a>
  </form>

  <form class="form" action="result.html" method="POST">
    <h1 class="productName">Div 4</h1>
    <img src="img\black.jpg" alt="Trial Image" width="10%" height="100%" class="images productImg"><br>
    <select name="category" class="package">
      <option value="Selected an option" default>Select an option</option>
      <option value="Business Plan">Business Plan</option>
      <option value="Feasibility Report">Feasibility Report</option>
    </select>

    <a href="" class="submit"><button type="submit" >Try it</button></a>
  </form>

</body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>

let testArrays = {

  'product101' :{
  'businessPlan': 'http://localhost/projects/link1a',
  'feasibilityReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link1b',
  'bizPlanReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link1c'
  },

  'product102' : {
    'businessPlan': 'http://localhost/projects/link2a',
    'feasibilityReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link2b',
    'bizPlanReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link2c'
  },

  'product103' : {
    'businessPlan': 'http://localhost/projects/link3a',
    'feasibilityReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link3b',
    'bizPlanReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link3c'
  },

  'product104' :{
    'businessPlan': 'http://localhost/projects/link4a',
    'feasibilityReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link4b',
    'bizPlanReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link4c'
  }

};


  const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".form");
  for (const form of forms) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      let package = this.querySelector('.package').value;

      if(package == 'Business Plan'){
        let link = this.querySelector('.submit').href = testArrays.product101.businessPlan;
        let message = this.querySelector('.submit').innerText = 'Try ' + package;
      } 
      else if(package == 'Feasibility Report'){
        let link = this.querySelector('.submit').href = testArrays.product102.feasibilityReport;
        let message = this.querySelector('.submit').innerText = 'Try ' + package;
      } 
      else {
          alert('You must select an option');
      }; 
    });
  }
```

My expectations is to have every array assigned to a div. I am thinking of how to use a for loop but not sure what to do.

Kindly correct me if am wrong or put me through with examples and solutions.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to associate a the link with a select value is to make the select value the same as the object key.

```html
<form id="form">
  <select name="select" id="mySelect">
    <option default value="choice1">Choice One</option>
    <option value="choice2">Choice Two</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
  let plans = {
    choice1: "https://mylink.com",
    choice2: "https://myotherlink.com"
  }

  let select = document.querySelector("#mySelect")
  let form = document.querySelector("#form")

  form.addEventListener("submit", event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert(plans[select.value])
  })
</script>
```

The option `value`s match the keys in the `plans` object, so they can be matched.

Here is a live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/static-ncgzp

Comment: But I have more than one object. You only specified for one product. I still have more products about 80 of them. They all will have choice one and choice two with their own links. Now how do I get for the other products.

Comment: let testArrays = {

  'product101' :{
  'businessPlan': 'http://localhost/projects/link1a',
  'feasibilityReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link1b',
  'bizPlanReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link1c'
  },

  'product102' : {
    'businessPlan': 'http://localhost/projects/link2a',
    'feasibilityReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link2b',
    'bizPlanReport': 'http://localhost/projects/link2c'
  }

};

Comment: That’s an example of my nested object. I am still going to add more of over 50 objects

Comment: Yes in that case each select needs a unique identifier so you can look it up in the nested object. You also need to add the event listener to each form and get the value of the specific select. Here's an example of how to do that: https://codesandbox.io/embed/static-mf9vq

Comment: Thanks @zackkrida so i modified it to open the link by making a few tweaks on the code

Comment: const forms = document.querySelectorAll(".form");
  for (const form of forms) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const formSelect = event.target.querySelector("select")
      window.location.assign(testArrays[formSelect.id][formSelect.value]);
    });
  }